# How do I know the public key of the person I need to pay?

Tags: wallet, public-key

As per the answer to [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/44644/how-to-get-the-public-keys-of-a-bitcoin-user), we cannot retrieve the public key of a user.

1)How does my wallet get the value (public key/public key hash) to which I need to make the payment?

2)What is the harm in exposing an address's public key?

Comment: Second question answered [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/42320/is-that-safe-to-expose-public-key-to-the-mainnet).  In general, please do not ask multiple questions in a single post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read through both questions, so please correct me if im answering the wrong question.

1. The user who you want to pay *must* send you their public key (or QR to scan) in order to send money to them. This is, of course, unless their public key (wallet) is listed on a public website. Please see https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Help:Introduction#Sending_payments
2. In general*, there is no harm in exposing a public key. This question on crypto stackexchange goes into more detail [Is exposing a public key bad?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/48433/57353)

Answer (score 1):

That person has to tell you what their public key (or its hash) is.  A Bitcoin address is the most convenient way to encode the hash of a public key, so typically the person will tell you an address and ask you to make a payment to that address.  You can enter that address into your wallet and make the payment.

Related: [How can a sender know receiver's public key when creating "Pay To Public Key" tx?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/48860/how-can-a-sender-know-receivers-public-key-when-creating-pay-to-public-key-tx?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `bitcoind`, you can get new receivable address using `bitcore-cli getnewaddress` command